# How to save a ggplot graph object into the r environment so it doesn't require dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, environment

I want to know how to save a ggplot graph object into the r environment so it doesn't require dataset. I've displayed some example code that illustrates my problem below.

I want to object to display the graph after removing the base dataset used to create the graph.

### --

```
# Sample graph for analyses

## loads package(s)
# ---- NOTE: for package tidyverse
if(!require(tidyverse)){install.packages("tidyverse")}
# ---- NOTE: for package ggplot2
if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages("ggplot2")}

## filters diamonds data so we have the first 300 rows
diamonds_top_300 <- head(diamonds, n = 300)

## creates graph
diamonds_top_300_graph <-
  ggplot(
    diamonds_top_300, 
    aes(
      x = 
        (diamonds_top_300[["carat"]])
      , 
      y = 
        (diamonds_top_300[["price"]])
    )
  ) + 
  geom_point(
    aes(
      colour = 
        (diamonds_top_300[[("color")]])
    ),
  )

## displays head of original data and then runs graph object
# ---- NOTE: shows head of data
head(diamonds_top_300)
# ---- NOTE: displays graph
diamonds_top_300_graph
# ---- NOTE: DOES WORK

## removes original dataset and then runs graph object
# ---- NOTE: removes appropriate object
remove(diamonds_top_300)
# ---- NOTE: displays graph
diamonds_top_300_graph
# ---- NOTE: DOES NOT WORK
```

Comment: Can you explain more what is motivating the request? How would opening a ggplot graph without / apart from its data help you achieve something? It strikes me as an interesting/unusual request that goes against the normal workflow, so it might help to understand the context better to help come up with a solution that addresses your underlying concerns.

Comment: Good question. I am making multiple graphs, both individually and as a list of graphs, filtering data from a main dataset as needed. I use the same name for the filtered dataset used to create different graphs. Because of this, there are errors that prevent graphs made earlier from rendering properly.

Comment: @neilfws's answer usefully recognizes that your nonstandard mapping is creating a link to the external data object that would not occur with normal mapping. Normally, ggplot will store the underlying data it uses, e.g. in `diamonds_top_300_graph$data`

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are using `aes` incorrectly. Instead of, for example:

```
aes(x = diamonds_top_300[["carat"]], ...)
```

You should use just the column name:

```
aes(x = carat, ...)
```

In the first case, `ggplot` is trying to calculate something using the data frame. That data is lost when the data frame is removed.

In the second, the data is saved as part of the `diamonds_top_300_graph` object, so the data is not lost.

So your code should read:

```
diamonds_top_300_graph <-
  ggplot(
    diamonds_top_300, 
    aes(
      x = carat,
      y = price,
    )
  ) + 
  geom_point(
    aes(
      colour = color 
    )
  )
```